# How use analog @Autowired annotation in JavaEE (@Inject)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inject

In Spring project I can use `@Autowired` annotation.

```
@Service
public class DefaultUserService implements UserService {
...
        @Autowired
        private UserDao userDao;
```

But I don't understand how do it in JavaEE project. I found:

@Inject
private AvayaDao avayaDao;

But my avayaDao is NULL. I tried add annotation

```
@Default
public class AvayaService {
...
@Inject
private AvayaDao avayaDao;
```

but not helped. It id my Dao:

```
public interface AvayaDao extends BaseDao<AvayaSdr> {

    List<AvayaSdr> getAll();
    void insertCdr(AvayaSdr avayaSdr);
}
```

It is My Service:

```
@Default
public class AvayaService {
    private static AvayaService instance;

    @Inject
    private AvayaDao avayaDao;

    public synchronized static AvayaService me() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AvayaService();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Set<String> selectAllLoadedAVAYAcmCDRFiles() {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        List<AvayaSdr> resultList = avayaDao.getAll();
        for (AvayaSdr avayaSdr : resultList) {
            result.add(avayaSdr.getHashValue());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void insertCdr(String fileHash) {
        AvayaSdr avayaCmCdr = new AvayaSdr("", fileHash, 0);
        avayaDao.insertCdr(avayaCmCdr);
    }

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

Either the AvayaDao must be an EJB and annotated with @Stateless or @Singleton or you use CDI injection and an empty beans.xml file is needed (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html) if you are using Java EE 6. In Java EE 7 the attribute bean-discovery-mode="all" must be set (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv001.htm).

UPDATE 1:

[Enterprise Java Beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans) are POJOS annotated with `@Stateless`, `@Statefull` or `@Singleton`, that are managed by the EJB container inside the application server. They are able to access container specific services like the TimerService, the security context and aspects like transaction support and monitoring. Stateless enterprise java beans are also pooled by the application server.

UPDATE 2:

@Tiny Your right, but if AvayaDao is no EJB and your application contains a beans.xml file, where interceptors or other CDI specific POJOS are registered the default bean-discovery-mode is 'annotated' and the injection will not work with not annotated POJOS and explicitly setting the 'all' value is needed (http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/when_your_di_breaks_bean). Another option would be using no beans.xml if you explicitly know, that your application is only deployed in JAVA EE 7 environments.

Comment: "*In Java EE 7, the attribute `bean-discovery-mode="all"` must be set.*" "*Must*"? Java EE 7 does not even mandate the `beans.xml` file.

Comment: I only mentioned because it was a confusing statement, especially the auxiliary verb "*Must*" which may make potential future readers confused. I was a victim of such incomplete statements in the past for a long time, when I started with Java EE along with Spring.